# Google Sheets API batchupdate - failed with error Empty response

Tags: google-sheets-api

I was trying to change the use of "range.setvalues" on a google apps script, because it was slow and found the solution of using Google Sheets API V4 for this..

I could put it to good use on my simpler basic tests.. but when tried with a big data range (50k rows), I get a generic error "sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Empty response" .. I am thinking this has something to do with some timeout on the API Call, but can't know for sure.. can't find it documented nowhere..

Thanks in advance

Edit1:
I just made a few tests, and the issue is not the number of rows, rather the number of cells.. Also, I made a "hack" that if my list is really long, I just slice the array in half.. and do 2 distinct calls to "batchupdate" ..

Edit2:
Here is an example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOkfvavBXovq4jezPpiEaWyr8hvDqCBx89nhUshlSLk/edit#gid=1762531043

On tab "1" you have data that I am copying to tab "2" just as an example..
The script is https://script.google.com/a/web-ideias.pt/d/M00DLl37KqCNrD96nt8GlLZJDjoEhHOGb/edit?mid=ACjPJvE45wbz2lcWpFBP6kGGBol53VgdXte-Y52ixCXY1NU29nPROED58L-wuBGtW27vYopq82wNZkwv3HNqxUxiR7vIOmvRKubzm0lDG9vXfbxnHzKuwI_nm2_m4IbGP0-TujMG8XV0ahJH&uiv=2 on the file "copy_1.gs"..

When trying to copy, there's the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkaxq.png)

Comment: I think in your question, more information is required to be provided. In order to replicate your issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Hi.. I just made a few tests, and the issue is not the number of rows, rather the number of cells..
Also, I made a "hack" that if my list is really long, I just slice the array in half.. and go 2 batchupdates ..

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.